# Saving integers in vector from string

Tags: c++, string, vector, atoi

I have this string which contains numbers divided from one another with a  `/`, like this `24/2/13`. I want to save them individually in  a vector of int,but it gives me this mistake `expected unqualified-id before '.' token|`. I know it might be a stupid mistake but that's just the qay for now :). Here is the code:

---

```
int t;
string s;
for(int i=0;i<final_states.size();i++)
{
    if(final_states.at(i)!='/')
        s.push_back(final_states.at(i));
    else
    {
        t=atoi(s.c_str());
        temp_final_states.push_back(t);
        s.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles: https://ideone.com/X0HiGL

Comment: @user36 Well, congratulations ... I guess? How do you expect anyone to help you if they can't reproduce your problem. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @user3658099 Which line does the compiler complain about?

Comment: @user877329 this line `temp_final_states.push_back(t);`

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your string always starts with a numeric value and the '/' character is not at the end of the string this should do it for you:

```
std::string final_states="24/2/13";
std::vector<int> temp_final_states;

temp_final_states.push_back(atoi(final_states.c_str()));
std::string::size_type index = final_states.find('/');

for (; index != std::string::npos; index = final_states.find('/', index) )
{
    ++index;
    const char* str = final_states.c_str() + index;
    temp_final_states.push_back(atoi(str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a compile error.
It looks like you are iterating over ***final_states***.  But then you try to call push_back() on ***temp_final_states***.  I assume you intend this to be the same collection.

Comment: No he didn't. `final_states` is a `string`, and `temp_final_states` is a `vector<int>`

Answer (score 0):

Refer following sample code http://ideone.com/id7E22

```
char str[] ="22/33/44";
  char * pch;
  cout<<"Splitting string into tokens:\n"<<str;
  pch = strtok (str,"/");
vector<int> vec;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    int val = atoi(pch);
    cout<<"   "<<val;
    vec.push_back(val);
    pch = strtok (NULL, "/");
  }
```